# Odoo Customizing : Many2one field in contacts view, which shows only the Individuals of the currently displayed Company

Tags: python, xml, odoo, customizing

[image]I am new to Odoo customizing an currently stuck on a Many2one field.
Following the Code Snippet I am working on:

This is my Python Code:

My One2many field:

```
field_contacts_customer_info = fields.One2many(
        'contacts.customer.information', 'another_id', string='Contacts for customer information')
```

My class:

```
class ContactsCustomerInformation(models.Model):
    _name = 'contacts.customer.information'
    _rec_name = 'name_contacts'

    name_contacts = fields.Many2one(
        'res.partner', string="Person", domain="[('is_company' , '=' , False)]")

    mail_contacts = fields.Char(
        related = 'name_contacts.email' ,string="Email")

    another_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner', string="AnotherID")

    @api.onchange('name_contacts')
    def onchange_name_contacts(self):
        if self.name_contacts:
            if self.name_contacts.email:
                self.mail_contacts = self.name_contacts.email
```

And my XML:

```
    <page name="contacts_customer_information" string="Contacts for customer information" attrs="{'invisible': [('is_company','=', False)]}">
                    <field name="field_contacts_customer_info">
                        <tree editable="bottom">
                            <field name="name_contacts"/>
                            <field name="mail_contacts" domain="[('is_company' , '=' , False)]"/>
                            <field name="another_id" invisible="1"/>
                            <field name="versuch" invisible="1"/>
                        </tree>
                            <form>
                                <group>
                                    <group>
                                        <field name="name_contacts" domain="[('is_company' , '=' , False)]"/>
                                    </group>
                                    <group>
                                        <field name="mail_contacts" domain="[('is_company' , '=' , False)]"/>
                                    </group>
                                </group>
                            </form>
                    </field>
                </page>
```

At the moment I have only one condition and that is that in the Many2one field no Companys but only Individuals are displayed. I also want to display only the Individuals that belong to the Company on whose view you are currently located.
I know that I have to link this with an AND condition.

What is the condition that only the Individuals of the currently displayed Company are displayed ?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the company field that related to res.partner.And then if you want to display individual that belong to this company ,try this

```html
class ContactsCustomerInformation(models.Model):
    _name = 'contacts.customer.information'
    _rec_name = 'name_contacts'


        
    name_contacts = fields.Many2one(
        'res.partner', string="Person", domain=[('parent_id','=',another_id)])

    mail_contacts = fields.Char(
        related = 'name_contacts.email' ,string="Email")

    another_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner', string="AnotherID")

    @api.onchange('name_contacts')
    def onchange_name_contacts(self):
        if self.name_contacts:
            if self.name_contacts.email:
                self.mail_contacts = self.name_contacts.email
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried it like you suggested but I get an error that says "object has no attribute child_ids". But I dont really get why it says that, because res.partner has a attribute which is called child_ids.

Comment: @kayalotta. Can you share your code.So I can suggest you more.

Comment: shure, I have added my code

Comment: @kayalotta. You used versuch in domain but you make it invisible and not filled data for this field in one2many field.That why you got error.

Comment: I made it invisible, because I dont want to display a third field. I only want to display the two fields name_contacts and mail_contacts. I did not get why you added the field company ?

Comment: @kayalotta. I misunderstood your question. I edited my answer.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but the Many2One field name_contacts still shows me all the Individuals of all companys an not only the Individuals of the company on which view I am currently on(I think because I am set as Superuser right now). BUT: Which Individuals are shown in the Many2one field shouldnt depend on the user and to which company he belongs but in which companys view the user is on. For example when I am on the view of company Azure Interior I want the Many2one field to show me only Individuals from Azure Interior even if the user isnt a AzureInterior Individual

Comment: @kayalotta.check my answwer.

Comment: Now it shows me the same selection on every companys view. I always get "Your company",so the company which I am assignet to, and the individuals that belong to that company.

Comment: I have added a picture, so maybe it is easier to unterstand. In the picture I am on the view of Azure Interior and in my One2many field I  would like to be able to select individuals from azure company only. But when I am on another companys view I want to only select from these companys individuals.

Comment: @kayalotta. I edited my answer.

Comment: I tried this and it gave me an internal server error saying "another_id" is not definded.

Comment: I also tried to put another_id in quotation marks but then the Many2one field displayed nothing

Comment: @kayalotta. Can you give me some testing environment with your code. So I can help easily.